# ASP.NET Identity UserManager: how to query on "Users" property?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-identity

I have written this `UserManager` and created a new method called `CountofPhoneNumberAsync` for it:

```
public class MyUserManager : UserManager<User, int>
{
    public MyUserManager(IUserStore<User, int> store)
        : base(store)
    {
    }

    public static MyUserManager Create(IdentityFactoryOptions<NazdiktarUserManager> options, IOwinContext context)
    {
        //normal UserManager Config
        //...
    }

    public async Task<int> CountofPhoneNumberAsync(string phoneNumber)
    {
        return await Users.CountAsync(x => x.PhoneNumber == phoneNumber);
    }
}
```

When I call this method to filter existing phone number in database, it does not work and I get this error:

> Sequence contains no elements

I also have tried to run other queries on `Users` property but all the queries do not return any data.

In Microsoft documentation said:

> Users returns an IQueryable of users if the store is an IQueryableUserStore

How can I run query on the `Users` property?

Answer (score 0):

**Make a collection of Identity Users:**

```
             IList<IdentityUser> listUsers = await userManager.GetUsersInRoleAsync("UserIE");
```

**Then examine that list for its user's properties:**

```
                             profilePhone = listUsers[i].PhoneNumber;
```